# Debugging advice: Cannot see inflated layout in emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, debugging, layout-inflater

I have a pretty general question, but I'm new to android development so all that I'm asking is for someone to hopefully point me in the right direction :)

Basically my issue is this, I inflate a layout (**layout1**) with **LayoutInflater** and then after an interval I inflate **layout2**. The issue is I never see layout2 appear in my emulator. The screen remains as layout1.

However, using **Stetho** to inspect what I see in the emulator, I can see that the views associated with layout1 are gone and only the views of layout2 remain. But this is not what I see displayed.

On top of this, clicking around on emulator screen, I can "click" the button view associated with layout2 (even though I cannot see it and can only see layout1).

Any ideas on how to further debug this issue would help. Again, I'm new so I apologize for the vagueness of the question. The code is quite lengthy and I'm not 100% how to shrink it down to a presentable size.

Comment: are you using fragment?

Comment: I am. RoboFragment. If that helps. @ShinilMS

Comment: show your code.